# Have Omnisharp-vim work with .razor files

Tags: vim, neovim

Can you have Omnisharp-vim work with .razor files? I.e. the @code bits. I've managed to get syntax highlighting on the rest of it by doing :setf html but how do you get C# intellisense on the rest of it? I'm using neovim on Ubuntu WSL.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Comment: @theTinMan I've tried to search for it and also read through the omnisharp-vim docs, I've got some idea of maybe using ale to do it but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding this [vim-polygot](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-polyglot) plugin. It worked for me and is superfast. Let me know whether or not it helps.

Comment: `vim-polygot` doesnt list razor in their language pack. How did you setup it up. Could you please provide guidance and config code?